# Sum each column of a sparse matrix multiplied by a vector

Tags: python, numpy, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large scipy **sparse** matrix `X`.
I have a vector, `y` with the number of elements matches the number of rows of `X`.

I want to calculate the sum of of each column after it was multiplies by `y`.
If `X` was dense, it is equivalent of `np.sum(X * y, axis=0)`.

How can it be done efficiently for a sparse matrix?

I tried:

```py
z = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

for i in range(X.shape[1]):
  z[i] = np.sum(np.array(X[:, i]) * y)
```

Yet it was terribly slow.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example (with code to generate the matrix)?

Comment: @mozway, Any matrix will do: `sp.sparse.random(m=50_000, n=40_000, density=5e-4)`

Comment: `X.transpose().dot(y)` should do the trick

Comment: @Onyambu, Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dot` product provided for sparse matrices:

```
X.transpose().dot(y)
```

This should be faster.

Also note that you cannot index a sparse matrix as you wrote in your example. You need to use `getcol` method.

Comment: for a CSR, `X[:, i]` works.  CSR does  lot of its indexing and summing with `@` and the appropriate 'extractor' matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj CSC and CSR support indexing, but in the example OP game in the comments, they are using COO and that does not support indexing

Comment: But even then `np.array(X...)` is the wrong way to 'densify' any sparse format. He may not have even tested that 'too slow' code on any matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj i wrote that to help them test the code i gave against their code to see that the two are equivalent